# Почему Python конвертирует строку в tuple

Tags: python

Например, есть такой код

```
            for i in range(maxRecordsToParse):
            chunkH = list(chunkedHrefs[i])
            chunkR = list(chunkedReceived[i])
            record = Record(received=chunkR[0],
                        posted=chunkR[1],
                        operator_name=chunkR[2],
                        number=chunkR[3],
                        operator_contact=chunkR[4] +' ' + chunkR[5],
                        status=chunkH[0],
                        status_date=chunkR[8],
                        well_name_number=chunkR[9] + ' ' + chunkR[10],
                        document_link=chunkH[1],
                        type_of_permit=chunkR[11],
                        well_location=chunkH[2],
                        footage_call=str(chunkR[13]),
                        objective_formation=chunkR[14],
                        proposed_td=chunkR[15],
                        field=str(chunkR[16]) + ' ' + str(chunkR[17]),
                        county=chunkR[18])
            filledRecords.append(record)
```

Код класса Record

```
class Record:
def __init__(self,
             received,
             posted,
             operator_name,
             number,
             operator_contact,
             status,
             status_date,
             well_name_number,
             document_link,
             type_of_permit,
             well_location,
             footage_call,
             objective_formation,
             proposed_td,
             field,
             county):
    self.received = received
    self.posted = posted,
    self.operator_name = operator_name,
    self.number = number,
    self.operator_contact = operator_contact,
    self.status = status,
    self.status_date = status_date,
    self.well_name_number = well_name_number,
    self.type_of_permit = type_of_permit
    self.document_link = document_link
    self.well_location = well_location,
    self.footage_call = footage_call,
    self.objective_formation = objective_formation,
    self.proposed_td = proposed_td,
    self.field = field,
    self.county = county
```

В итоге 90% полей класса Record - tuple, причем первое значение у него как раз таки искомая строка, а второе - пустое
Например `('GRAND VALLEY',)`

Comment: Во-первых, поправьте форматирование кода, во-вторых, не понятно, чем являются элементы `chunkedHrefs[i]` и `chunkedReceived[i]`? Видимо, как раз таки там и есть `tuple`.

Comment: Питон, как и любой другой ЯП, не делает ничего, о чем его не просят. Разбирайтесь со структурами `chunkedHrefs` и `chunkedReceived`.

Comment: chunkedHrefs и chunkedReceived всего лишь лист листов [ ['строка','строка', .... ],  ['строка','строка', .... ],  ... ]

Comment: Зачем тогда вы их ещё раз оборачиваете в `list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В коде вашего класса Record нужно убрать запятые в конце строк.

Выражение вида

```
x,
```

трактуется интерпретатором как тупл из одного элемента.
Кстати, это именно тупл из единственного элемента, а не из двух элементов, где второе - пустое.

Запятую в конце строки следует ставить только в том случае, когда вы разбиваете на несколько строк некоторую последовательность.
Но если у вас не многострочная последовательность, а единственный элемент, то запятая после него не нужна.

Comment: ФЕЙСПАЛМ. Действительно, глупо получилось. Пересел только с си шарпа на пайтон и работал всю ночь, недоглядел, наверное XD